# How to gain access to /data directory through ADB shell

Tags: adb, root-access, shell

[image]

Despite the fact that I have root access, nevertheless I can not work with this directory. But why?

Info about my phone:

- Android version - 6.0.1
- Android security patch level - 2016-11-01
- Kernel version - 3.18.19+

Comment: DIsable selinux and then try.

Comment: @Firelord setting it to "permissive" should be sufficient I guess. But could you give a pointer on how to do either of the two?

Comment: SELinux must be the reason. You are running with context untrusted_app which won't be able to access /data with context system_data_file. Set SELinux permissive or add a policy statement with supolicy tool.

Comment: You must be running adb daemon with root access i.e. 'adb root'. Instead if you start adb as normal daemon and then enter a root shell with su command, your context will also be changed to su (su daemon's injected context) which can access almost everything on phone.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting SELinux to permissive then access `/data` again:

```
ibug@android:/ # setenforce 0
ibug@android:/ # ls -l /data
(output)
```

Comment: I tryed it, but occur error: "setenforce: Couldn't set enforcing status to '0': Permission denied"

Comment: @SNMetamorph Did you run the command with root?

Comment: Yes, through ADB - i.imgur.com/jJX9BqH.png